# Csharp web page redirection to blank page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

since I'm working on a new project using asp.net core (as a begginer) I don't have good knowledge on C# .
Short, I face an error that I can't find a solution for it.

when I get acces to "Create User" the web .cshtml page load the view: [createUSER.cshtml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/469uw.jpg)

but after seconds it redirect me to new blank page that have **"2023"** : [blank page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZmcv.jpg) without any console error as you can see here : [console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdLxw.jpg)
any one have an Idea **please help me**!!

this is my cshtml Code :

```cshtml
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create User";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<div class="kt-content  kt-grid__item kt-grid__item--fluid">
    <div class="kt-portlet kt-portlet--mobile">
        <div class="kt-portlet__head">
            <div class="kt-portlet__head-label">
                <span class="kt-portlet__head-icon kt-hidden">
                    <i class="la la-gear"></i>
                </span>
                <h3 class="kt-portlet__head-title">
                    @ViewBag.Title
                </h3>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div id="FILTERZONE"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal fade" id="kt_modal_4" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" style="display: none;" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">GDA Fonction</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

            </div>
            <div class="kt-portlet__body kt-portlet__body--fit">

                <!--begin: Datatable -->
                <div class="kt-datatable" id="json_data"></div>

                <!--end: Datatable -->
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal fade" id="kt_modal_5" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" style="display: none;" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">GDA Parametre</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

            </div>
            <div class="kt-portlet__body kt-portlet__body--fit">

                <!--begin: Datatable -->
                <div class="kt-datatable" id="json_data1"></div>

                <!--end: Datatable -->
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@section Scripts{

    <script>
    @*var getUrlParameter = function getUrlParameter(sParam) {
        var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1),
            sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&'),
            sParameterName,
            i;
        for (i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
            sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
            if (sParameterName[0] === sParam) {
                return sParameterName[1] === undefined ? true : decodeURIComponent(sParameterName[1]);
            }
        }
    };*@
    var ProcedureName = "GETUSER_GDA";
    var ProcedureName2 = "GETUSER_PARA";
    var whereQueryName = " 1=1";
    var datatable;
    var datatable2;
    var KTDatatableJsonRemoteDemo = function () {
        // Private functions
        // basic demo
        var demo = function () {
            var modal = $('#kt_modal_4');
            datatable = $('#json_data').KTDatatable({
                // datasource definition
                data: {
                    type: 'remote',
                    source: {
                        read: {
                            url: '@Url.Action("GetDataJsonForGrid", "Shared")',
                            params: {
                                "Procedure": ProcedureName,
                                "whereQuery": whereQueryName,
                            },
                            timeout: 300000,
                            map: function (raw) {
                                // sample data mapping
                                var dataSet = raw;
                                if (typeof raw.Data !== 'undefined') {
                                    dataSet = raw.Data;
                                }
                                KTApp.unblockPage();
                                return dataSet;
                            },
                        },
                    },
                },

                // layout definition
                layout: {
                    scroll: true, // enable/disable datatable scroll both horizontal and vertical when needed.
                    footer: false,
                    height: 400,

                },
                sortable: true,




                // columns definition
                columns: [
                    {
                        field: 'lib_fam',
                        title: 'Famille',
                        autoHide: false,
                    },
                    {
                        field: 'lib_fun',
                        title: 'Fonction',
                        autoHide: false,

                    }, {
                        field: '',
                        title: 'LinK',
                        autoHide: false,
                        template: function (row) {
                            return '<span>../' + row.cont_web + '/' + row.act_web + '</span>'
                        }

                    },
                    {
                        field: 'Actions',
                        title: 'Actions',
                        sortable: false,
                        autoHide: false,
                        overflow: 'visible',
                        template: function (row) {

                            if (row.access==='1') {
                                return '\
                        <div><span class="kt-switch kt-switch--icon">\
                                                            <label>\
                                                                <input type="checkbox" data-id="' + row.id + '" id="BtnACCESS" checked="checked" name="">\
                                                                <span></span>\
                                                            </label>\
                                                        </span></div>';
                            }
                            else {
                                return '\
                        <span class="kt-switch kt-switch--icon">\
                                                            <label>\
                                                                <input type="checkbox" data-id="' + row.id + '" id="BtnACCESS"  name="">\
                                                                <span></span>\
                                                            </label>\
                                                        </span>';
                            }

                        },
                    }],

            });
            datatable.hide();
            var alreadyReloaded = false;
            modal.on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
                if (!alreadyReloaded) {
                    var modalContent = $(this).find('.modal-content');
                    datatable.spinnerCallback(true, modalContent);

                    datatable.reload();

                    datatable.on('kt-datatable--on-layout-updated', function () {
                        datatable.show();
                        datatable.spinnerCallback(false, modalContent);
                        datatable.redraw();
                    });

                    alreadyReloaded = true;
                }
            });


        };
        var demo2 = function () {
            var modal = $('#kt_modal_5');
            datatable2 = $('#json_data1').KTDatatable({
                 data: {
                    type: 'remote',
                    source: {
                        read: {
                            url: '@Url.Action("GetDataJsonForGrid", "Shared")',
                            params: {
                                "Procedure": ProcedureName2,
                                "whereQuery": whereQueryName,
                            },
                            timeout: 300000,
                            map: function (raw) {
                                // sample data mapping
                                var dataSet = raw;
                                if (typeof raw.Data !== 'undefined') {
                                    dataSet = raw.Data;
                                }
                                KTApp.unblockPage();
                                return dataSet;

                            },
                        },
                    },

                },
                // layout definition
                layout: {
                    scroll: true, // enable/disable datatable scroll both horizontal and vertical when needed.
                    footer: false,
                    height: 400,

                },
                sortable: true,
                 // columns definition
                columns: [
                    {
                        field: 'lib_fam',
                        title: 'Famille',
                        autoHide: false,
                    },
                    {
                        field: 'lib_fun',
                        title: 'Fonction',
                        autoHide: false,

                    }, {
                        field: 'description',
                        title: 'Description',
                        autoHide: false,
                    },
                    {
                        field: 'Actions',
                        title: 'Actions',
                        sortable: false,
                        autoHide: false,
                        overflow: 'visible',
                        template: function (row) {

                            if (row.access === '1') {
                                return '\
                        <div><span class="kt-switch kt-switch--icon">\
                                                            <label>\
                                                                <input type="checkbox" data-id="' + row.id + '" id="BtnACCESS" checked="checked" name="">\
                                                                <span></span>\
                                                            </label>\
                                                        </span></div>';
                            }
                            else {
                                return '\
                        <span class="kt-switch kt-switch--icon">\
                                                            <label>\
                                                                <input type="checkbox" data-id="' + row.id + '" id="BtnACCESS"  name="">\
                                                                <span></span>\
                                                            </label>\
                                                        </span>';
                            }

                        },
                    }],
            });
            datatable2.hide();
            var alreadyReloaded = false;
            modal.on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
                if (!alreadyReloaded) {
                    var modalContent = $(this).find('.modal-content');
                    datatable2.spinnerCallback(true, modalContent);
                    datatable2.reload();
                    datatable2.on('kt-datatable--on-layout-updated', function () {
                        datatable2.show();
                        datatable2.spinnerCallback(false, modalContent);
                        datatable2.redraw();
                    });

                    alreadyReloaded = true;
                }
            });


        };
        return {
            // public functions
            init: function () {

                demo();
                demo2();
            }
        };
    }();

    jQuery(document).ready(function () {


        KTApp.blockPage({
            overlayColor: '#000000',
            type: 'v2',
            state: 'success',
            message: 'Merci de Patienter...'
        });

        KTApp.init(KTAppOptions);
       //
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("GETHTMLUserCreate", "Administration")',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {
                $("#FILTERZONE").replaceWith(data);
                KTApp.unblockPage();
            },
            error: function (data) {


            }
        });

        $(this).on("click", "#BTNSAVE", function () {
            KTApp.blockPage({
                overlayColor: '#000000',
                type: 'v2',
                state: 'success',
                message: 'Merci de Patienter...'
            });
            var $buttonClicked = $(this);
            var ID_User = $buttonClicked.attr('data-id');

            if (ID_User === '')
            {
                var USER_NAME = $('input[name="USER_NAME"]').val();
                var Email = $('input[name="Email"]').val();
                var FirstName = $('input[name="FirstName"]').val();
                var LastName = $('input[name="LastName"]').val();
                var P_ROLE = $('select[name="P_ROLE"]').find(":selected").val();
                var P_SOC = $('select[name="P_SOC"]').find(":selected").val();
                var P_GROUPE = $('select[name="P_GROUPE"]').find(":selected").val();
                var Table = 'WEB_USER';
                var USERmod = '**';
                var UpdateQuery = "(Username,FirstName,LastName,ID_ROLE,ID_SOC,ID_GROUP,Email) values ('" + USER_NAME + "','" + FirstName + "','" + LastName + "','" +
                    P_ROLE + "','" + P_SOC + "','" + P_GROUPE + "','" +Email+ "')";

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '@Url.Action("InsertIntoTable", "Shared")',
                    traditional: true,
                    data: { Table: Table, UpdateQuery: UpdateQuery, USERmod: USERmod  },
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert(data.error);
                        if (data.error === 0) {
                             $.ajax({
                                type: "POST",
                                url: '@Url.Action("GETID_USERBYUSERNAME", "Administration")',
                                traditional: true,
                                data: { USER_NAME: USER_NAME },
                                dataType: 'json',
                                success: function (data) {
                                    if (true) {
                                        $buttonClicked.attr('data-id', data);
                                        $('button[id="BTNGDA"]').attr('data-id', data);
                                        $('button[id="BTNPARA"]').attr('data-id', data);
                                        $('#BTNGDA').removeAttr("disabled");
                                        $('#BTNPARA').removeAttr("disabled");
                                        $('input[id="USER_NAME"]').attr("disabled", true);
                                        KTApp.unblockPage();
                                        swal.fire("Success", "ajout avec success", "success");
                                        whereQueryName = data;
                                        KTDatatableJsonRemoteDemo.init();

                                    }

                                },
                                error: function (data) {
                                    KTApp.unblockPage();
                                }
                            });
                            KTApp.unblockPage();
                        }
                        else {

                            KTApp.unblockPage();
                            swal.fire("Erreur", "User Name existe deja", "error");
                        }

                    },
                    error: function (data) {
                        KTApp.unblockPage();
                    }
                });

            }
            else {

                var ID_User = $buttonClicked.attr('data-id');
                var Email = $('input[name="Email"]').val();
                var FirstName = $('input[name="FirstName"]').val();
                var LastName = $('input[name="LastName"]').val();
                var P_ROLE = $('select[name="P_ROLE"]').find(":selected").val();
                var P_SOC = $('select[name="P_SOC"]').find(":selected").val();
                var P_GROUPE = $('select[name="P_GROUPE"]').find(":selected").val();
                var Table = 'WEB_USER';
                var whereQuery = "ID_USER='" + whereQueryName + "'";
                var USERmod = '**';
                var UpdateQuery = "FirstName='" + FirstName + "'," +
                    "LastName='" + LastName + "'," +
                    "ID_ROLE='" + P_ROLE + "'," +
                    "ID_SOC='" + P_SOC + "'," +
                    "ID_GROUP='" + P_GROUPE + "'," + "Email='" + Email + "'";
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '@Url.Action("UpdateValue", "Shared")',
                    traditional: true,
                    data: { Table: Table, UpdateQuery: UpdateQuery, USERmod: USERmod, whereQuery: whereQuery },
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (data) {
                        swal.fire("Success", "mise à jour fait", "success");
                        KTApp.unblockPage();
                    },
                    error: function (data) {
                        KTApp.unblockPage();
                    }
                });

            }

        });
        $('#json_data').on("click", "#BtnACCESS", function () {
            KTApp.blockPage({
                overlayColor: '#000000',
                type: 'v2',
                state: 'success',
                message: 'Merci de Patienter...'
            });
            if (this.checked) {
                //alert('true');
                $.ajax({

                    url: '@Url.Action("Update_GDA_FUN", "Administration")',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    data: { ID_GDA: 1, ETAT: true },
                    success: function (data) {
                            KTApp.unblockPage();
                    },
                    error: function (data) {
                        KTApp.unblockPage();
                    }
                });
            }
            else {
                // alert('false');
                $.ajax({

                    url: '@Url.Action("Update_GDA_FUN", "Administration")',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    data: { ID_GDA: 1, ETAT: false },
                    success: function (data) {
                            KTApp.unblockPage();
                    },
                    error: function (data) {
                        KTApp.unblockPage();
                    }
                });

            }
        });
        $('#json_data1').on("click", "#BtnACCESS", function () {
            KTApp.blockPage({
                overlayColor: '#000000',
                type: 'v2',
                state: 'success',
                message: 'Merci de Patienter...'
            });
            if (this.checked) {
                //alert('true');
                $.ajax({

                    url: '@Url.Action("Update_GDA_PAR", "Administration")',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    data: { ID_GDA: 1, ETAT: true },
                    success: function (data) {
                        KTApp.unblockPage();
                    },
                    error: function (data) {
                        KTApp.unblockPage();
                    }
                });
            }
            else {
                // alert('false');
                $.ajax({

                    url: '@Url.Action("Update_GDA_PAR", "Administration")',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    data: { ID_GDA: 1, ETAT: false },
                    success: function (data) {
                        KTApp.unblockPage();
                    },
                    error: function (data) {
                        KTApp.unblockPage();
                    }
                });

            }
        });

    });
    </script>
}
```

Comment: This may have something to do with code inside the cshtml file. If you want more detail, provide more detail to look at. "before that" - before ... what exactly?

Comment: I make some changes and maybe that's why the page doesn't load properly

Comment: Please provide your code as text directly in your question. Don't provide images of your code. Links to images tend to break, images can't be indexed by search engines easily, it's hard to copy code into answers, and it makes potential answerers go through mores steps to help you. Also - remove all irrelevant tags from your question. If you're using asp.net-core, then tag that. Don't tag random other things like asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-web-api etc.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution; it was in the user access rights in the project `Controller.cs`. Here is the code below that makes the **blank page redirection**:

```cs
public ActionResult GETHTMLUserCreate()
{
    if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
    }
}

// This is the old code that caused the problem:
/*
if (!User.IsInRole("8"))
{
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}*/
    
if (!User.IsInRole("11"))
{
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}

String Resultat = "";
string guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
int? ERROR = 0;
DataClasses1DataContext dbcontext = new DataClasses1DataContext();
dbcontext.GET_USER_CREATE_VIEW(guid, User.Identity.Name, ref ERROR);

var data = from c in dbcontext.Temp_View_Creates where c.ID_Guid == guid orderby c.ID_Ordre select c;
                foreach (var item in data)
                {
                    Resultat += item.Code_HTML;
                }
                dbcontext.Del_CODE_GENRATE(guid);
                return Content(Resultat);
            }
```

I just change the number **8** with **11** to make it equal with the access in the database user access.